How to vectorize Scipy.integrate.quad()
I have a 1D function f(t) defined on an interval [t0, t1]. I would like to obtain an integral of this function, uniformly sampled over the above interval with a timestep delta_t. The naive solution for this is to use scipy.integrate.quad inside of a python for-loop
rez = np.zeros(nStep-1)
for i in range(1, nStep):
    rez[i-1] = scipy.integrate.quad(my_func, t0, t0 + i * delta_t)

I presume that this is not the fastest way to perform such an integral. Is there an intended way to do this operation in a vectorized form?
One improvement I can think of is to do piecewise integration, then sum up, because, for every iteration, the integrator will have to deal with simpler functions (less wiggles).
rez = np.zeros(nStep-1)
for i in range(1, nStep):
    rez[i-1] = scipy.integrate.quad(my_func, t0 + (i - 1) * delta_t, t0 + i * delta_t)
rez = np.cumsum(rez)


Do you want to calculate the final integral value, or do you want to store the value of each individual integral section?

@9769953 I want to know the integral value at all timesteps. The first piece of code best represents the spirit of what I want to achieve, except I am looking to speed it up. I need to compute the integral for many values of the upper bound, because I need to represent the result as a mathematical function. That function is an intermediate quantity in my calculation, and, among others, I will need to integrate it the second time later down the line

Does scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid do what you're looking for?

if you're willing to use other packages, you can use NumbaQuadpack

@jared Kind of, but not really. The function does the correct thing - it integrates all segments. However, trapezoid rule is only accurate for piecewise-linear functions. I am looking for a general solution that can account for curvature.

@Nin17 Sure, why not. I have had a brief look at the github page, but did not find documentation. Could you point me to a minimal example for the problem I am solving, or relevant documentation? If possible, I would prefer to avoid writing C/Fortran ports myself and stick to whatever is available in Python already.

@AleksejsFomins So how about scipy.integrate.cumulative_simpson?

@jared Maybe it is good enough for my specific application, I have to check. Thanks for pointing it out.

nicholaswogan - this is the stack overflow link to the author of the package, a few of the answers contain code that uses NumbaQuadpack


One improvement I can think of is to do piecewise integration, then sum up, because, for every iteration, the integrator will have to deal with simpler functions (less wiggles).

This is the right way indeed. If the integrand is simple enough and smooth enough, you can cook up your own Simpson or a trapezoid cumulative integration. For non-trivial integrands though, delegating to quad on each sub interval makes more sense indeed.

What you suggest makes sense, but that does not fully answer my question. The main question is whether Scipy foresees vectorized functionality for such use cases, or whether I have to do it manually, e.g. via Numba. I just want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel

There is not much in scipy as is, no. For vector functions, there's quad_vec, for cumulative integrarion, like here, there's cumulative_trapezoid, both in the integrate name space. Since quad is adaptive under the hood, it does not play well with what you seem to be after, not out of the box at least.

And BTW, the OP example is not "vectorization" really since you've a loop dependency on the upper limit.

@ev-br I think that's the point: to process integrate.quad for multiple (different) spans at the same time (some other functions in scipy and numpy do this; or at least, such functions are optimized under the hood with a C loop instead of a Python for loop). The input vector would  be an array of end timestamps as argument for integrate.quad.

Yes, and? Quad does not do it. If the loop is too slow (profile!), there are multiple ways to  improve perf on the user side. Threads or processes; push the integrand in to a LowLevelCallable, loop in cython and call the QUADPACK bindings if one is really desperate. The last part is borderline insane, though. Just throwing numba is unlikely to magically help though.
